# CLR trigger in a web-application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, clr, signalr

I just started using SQL-CLR for creating a very basic trigger... but while I did that another question "poped up"..
Is there anyway to actually make a SQL-trigger to trigger a method inside a web-application?..
My first idea was to have a web service which would be located in the web-applicatoion which the SQL-CLR then called..
The whole idea is that once the trigger gets "triggered".. it will call a SignalR-hub which then alerts the client about that something happened in the database..
the whole thing is more experimental for me..
The reason I cant use the web-service-way.. is that it would require an additional request for each time the trigger gets "triggered"

Answer (score 5):

Do not make HTTP calls from triggers. Introducing such coupling will bring performance to its knees, will decrease availability, increase latency and make the system extremely fragile (HTTP failures cause trigger failures which cause transaction failures).

Instead decouple the HTTP call from the trigger. In the trigger place the request for the call in a [queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) and have the HTTP request be done from an external process that monitors the queue.

Systems that monitor for database changes already exists, [Query Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for live changes and [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for disconnected systems.

Comment: Do you have any example site where I can read more about what you described about the queue-thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh!.. And well.. the actuall thing im trying to accomplish is that I dont want to need an additional request.. I simply want the trigger to execute a function in the webapplication without the need of a web service or any form of HTTP request..Im not sure if its even possible :).. but well.. :)

Comment: Now I get the queue thing.. you meen like an additional application that reads the queue and then does the HTTP request.. for instance a windows service..